# Find highest values in similarity matrix not on diagonal

Tags: python, matrix, numpy

Say I have the following [similarity matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Similarity_matrix):

```
matrix = [[100.0, 66.666666666666671, 61.539999999999999, 59.260000000000005, 59.260000000000005, 82.61333333333333, 61.539999999999999, 61.539999999999999, 61.539999999999999, 78.259999999999991],
[66.666666666666671, 100.0, 91.306666666666672, 87.5, 87.5, 69.233333333333334, 91.306666666666672, 91.306666666666672, 91.306666666666672, 65.386666666666656],
[61.539999999999999, 91.306666666666672, 100.0, 88.0, 88.0, 70.373333333333335, 91.666666666666671, 91.666666666666671, 100.0, 66.666666666666671],
[59.260000000000005, 87.5, 88.0, 100.0, 84.620000000000005, 74.079999999999998, 95.833333333333329, 95.833333333333329, 88.0, 64.286666666666662],
[59.260000000000005, 87.5, 88.0, 84.620000000000005, 100.0, 67.859999999999999, 88.0, 88.0, 88.0, 64.286666666666662],
[82.61333333333333, 69.233333333333334, 70.373333333333335, 74.079999999999998, 67.859999999999999, 100.0, 76.926666666666662, 76.926666666666662, 76.926666666666662, 87.5],
[61.539999999999999, 91.306666666666672, 91.666666666666671, 95.833333333333329, 88.0, 76.926666666666662, 100.0, 100.0, 91.666666666666671, 66.666666666666671],
[61.539999999999999, 91.306666666666672, 91.666666666666671, 95.833333333333329, 88.0, 76.926666666666662, 100.0, 100.0, 91.666666666666671, 66.666666666666671],
[61.539999999999999, 91.306666666666672, 100.0, 88.0, 88.0, 76.926666666666662, 91.666666666666671, 91.666666666666671, 100.0, 66.666666666666671],
[78.259999999999991, 65.386666666666656, 66.666666666666671, 64.286666666666662, 64.286666666666662, 87.5, 66.666666666666671, 66.666666666666671, 66.666666666666671, 100.0]]
```

Note that the values on the diagonal are all equal to 100.0 and that the upper triangular is equal to the lower triangular.

I want to find the indexes of the five different highest values not on the diagonal.

For the moment I do this brute force way:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
for i in range(len(matrix)):
    for j in range(len(matrix[i])):
      d[matrix[i][j]].append((i,j))

for value in sorted(d.keys(), reverse=True)[1:6]:
    print value, d[value]
```

Which gives:

```
95.8333333333 [(3, 6), (3, 7), (6, 3), (7, 3)]
91.6666666667 [(2, 6), (2, 7), (6, 2), (6, 8), (7, 2), (7, 8), (8, 6), (8, 7)]
91.3066666667 [(1, 2), (1, 6), (1, 7), (1, 8), (2, 1), (6, 1), (7, 1), (8, 1)]
88.0 [(2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 2), (3, 8), (4, 2), (4, 6), (4, 7), (4, 8), (6, 4), (7, 4), (8, 3), (8, 4)]
87.5 [(1, 3), (1, 4), (3, 1), (4, 1), (5, 9), (9, 5)]
```

But this is inefficient because I go through the whole matrix while I only need to traverse half the matrix: for the highest value `95.8333333333` I only care about the indices `(3,6)` and `(3,7)`.

Is there a more efficient way to do this, perhaps using numpy?

Comment: There were 100.0 elements that were not on diagonal too!

Comment: @Antii Haapala Gooed catch! I would like those as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from heapq import nlargest
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

for i in xrange(len(matrix)):
    for j in xrange(i):
      d[matrix[i][j]].append((i, j))

for value, positions in nlargest(5, d.items(), key=lambda item: item[0]):
    print value, positions
```

- use xrange instead of range
- loop j only to i - 1 (if i = 0, then the inner loop is never run...)
- for the efficient use, do not sort the list, but use nlargest from heapq
  as it uses the heap data structure for this. It should matter for large matrices.

Answer (score 1):

Numpy will be faster.

```
import numpy as np

m = np.array(matrix) * np.diag(len(matrix)) # set the upper triangle to zero
for top_value in sorted((np.unique(m)), reverse=True)[1:6]:
    print top_value, zip(*np.where(m == top_value))
```